# Firebase A/B Testing: Using Event Counts as Goals?

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I am trying to figure out how to track engagement using a Firebase A/B test and I am a bit lost. Here's the scenario

I am building a chat app. An user becomes activated once they send the first message (logged as `first_message`). From here, I want to test a new feature that would increase the engagement in the app. I currently think of engagement in terms of messages sent (logged as `sent_message`)

Here's how I would see this:

Create a new A/B test where the activation event is `first_message` and the goal metric is `sent_message`. I expect the variant with the best engagement to produce the largest amount of `sent_message` events

But that doesnt seem to be what happens. It seems that Firebase A/B tests work in terms of conversions? They look at whether a user first hit `first_message`, and then if they hit any number of `sent_message`. If the user sent any number of messages, Firebase considers it a conversion, and counts it as **1 conversion**

Surely, I must be missing something here. A/B tests built around the number of fired events seems like a fundamental feature, there is no way this was not considered while building the platform. Am I going about it wrong?

Thanks!